# CSS3: 3d-анимация в IE

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation, 3d

Хочу использовать на сайте вот такую анимацию:

```css
.wrap {
  margin-top: 50px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

.cube {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cube > div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateY(-50px);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(270deg) translateY(50px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

.cube {
  animation: rotate 20s infinite linear;
}

.cube:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front">
      Front side
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      Back side
    </div>
    <div class="top">
      Top side
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      Bottom side
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Прекрасно работает во всех браузерах кроме IE (у меня 11). Есть ли какие-то лайфхаки, чтобы анимация корректно работала в эксплорере? Или отдельно для IE всё-таки придётся делать другое решение?

Answer (score 0):

Есть сайт с информацией о css свойствах (и html тегах) и поддержки их в разных браузерах

https://caniuse.com/

В данном случае часть свойств IE просто не поддерживаются:

*"Partial support in IE refers to not supporting the `transform-style: preserve-3d` property. This prevents nesting 3D transformed elements."*

Так что для IE придется делать или javascript управление или...

подобный вопрос уже задавался на параллельном сайте:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848328/css3-3d-transform-doesnt-work-on-ie11

Посмотрите - может поможет

Comment: про caniuse знаю, мой вопрос не про то, почему не работает в ie, а про то, есть ли какие-то "костыли" для ie. за ссылку спасибо - посмотрю

Comment: я бы выделил 6 независимых div (плоскости) и для каждой делал бы свою анимацию, потому что сейчас вращение как бы описано у родительского div только, а тут будет 6 независимых но синхранизованных конструкций